# How can I map the power key on the keyboard to shut down the laptop?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, shutdown, power, lenovo-laptop

I have recently bought a Lenovo IdeaPad 520 notebook with Windows 10 Home (x64) pre-installed. This laptop does not have a dedicated power button off its keyboard. That is, the power button is actually a key on the keyboard itself. See the image:

[image: keyboard]

My previous laptop, Lenovo G580 with Windows 10 Pro (x86), had a dedicated power button near the hinge. I was used to pressing the power button to shut the laptop down easily. But my new laptop's power key, it seems, can only power on the laptop or force shut it down on being pressed and held for a few seconds. It doesn't shut down Windows if pressed once. I have set the power button action, in the power settings, to Shut Down on both battery and plugged-in modes. In fact, not only the Shut Down option but also other options such as Sleep and Turn off the display don't work.

So, is there a way I can manually map the power key to shut down Windows using registry hack or a third-party software?

I have searched high and low but couldn't find a solution to this problem. Even Lenovo's forums were useless. I hope someone here can help me. Thank you.

Comment: The fact that the power button looks like and is lined up with the keyboard does not mean it actually is just a regular keyboard key. In fact I'd think NOT having a dedicated button with low-level hooks at the BIOS level would be a poor design choice. Are you sure you've set the Power Options correctly?

Comment: @wysiwyg Yeah of course I have set the power options correctly. That's very basic. I even checked the power options individually for each power plan (balanced, power saver and high-performance); all have the power button action set to Shut down.

Comment: There may be a tiny driver just for the power button on the Lenovo software download page for this laptop.  I've seen it for Dells.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage There's only an ACPI driver under Power Management. Nothing else credible. The Lenovo settings apps pre-installed on my laptop also don't have any related settings :/

Comment: This problem is bothering me much more than it should.